# converting string containing keys and values into array

Tags: php, arrays, string

does anyone know an elagant way of turning this string (the list is not definite.. the "keys" and "values" can be added arbitrarily)

```
business_type,cafe|business_type_plural,cafes|sample_tag,couch|business_name,couch cafe
```

into this array?

```
array(
     [business_type]=>'cafe'
     [business_type_plural] => 'cafes'
     [sample_tag]=>'couch'
     [business_name]=>'couch cafe'
     )
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Explode it!

```
$string = "business_type,cafe|business_type_plural,cafes|sample_tag,couch|business_name,couch cafe";

$finalArray = array();

$asArr = explode( '|', $string );

foreach( $asArr as $val ){
  $tmp = explode( ',', $val );
  $finalArray[ $tmp[0] ] = $tmp[1];
}

print_r( $finalArray );
```

This will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [business_type] => cafe
    [business_type_plural] => cafes
    [sample_tag] => couch
    [business_name] => couch cafe
)
```