# converting array containing keys and values into string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array it contains key and value. i would like to converting into a string.

```
array(
 [business_type]=>'cafe'
 [business_type_plural] => 'cafes'
 [sample_tag]=>'couch'
 [business_name]=>'couch cafe'
 )
```

Expected Output:

```
business_type,cafe|business_type_plural,cafes|sample_tag,couch|business_name,couch cafe
```

NOTE:

I was searching in StackOverflow and found the below question and it has answer. I want exactly reverse one.

[converting string containing keys and values into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033282/converting-string-containing-keys-and-values-into-array)

Comment: use implode instead of explode =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$data = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
  $data[] = $key.','.$value;
}
echo implode('|',$data);
```

Another Solution:

```
function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $delimiter)
{
    $item1 = "$key".$delimiter."$item1";
}

array_walk($arr, 'test_alter',',');
echo implode('|',$arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `foreach()` function to go through the array and string the keys/values together...

Assuming your array is called `$array`

```
$result = "";
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $result .= $key . "," . $value . "|";
}
```

It's as simple as that.

EDIT - Thanks **Nelson**

After that, lost the last `|`

```
$result = rtrim($result, "|");
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the extra `|` at the end. That's why I prefer GBD's `implode` method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$pieces=array();
foreach(array('key1'=>'val1', 'key2'=>'val2', 'key3'=>'val3') as $k=>$v)
{
    $pieces[]=$k.','.$v;
}
echo implode('|', $pieces);
```