# I'm trying to add keys and values from a string to an array, but it isn't creating tre keys. What's wrong?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
```

And it prints, which is all right:

```
Array ( [Peter] => 35 [Ben] => 37 [Joe] => 43 )
```

But I want to do add values from a string, like this:

```
$string = '"Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43"';
$age = array($string);
```

The problem is that it prints:

```
Array ( [0] => "Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43" )
```

I don't want this:

```
[0] =>
```

And the keys are not right. It don't turn the "" to []:

```
Right: [Peter] => ...  
Wrong: "Peter" => ...
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: Add a language tag to your question.

Comment: This is from a PHP tutorial on W3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp about halfway down). I think your problem is confusing strings and arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting array containing keys and values into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767416/converting-array-containing-keys-and-values-into-string)

Comment: Hi ecg8,
I've actually used this data from w3schools, but only the data entries, since I want to achieve another goal than showed there.

Comment: ecg8, I tried the approach you sugested above, but it still isn't getting the expected results. I applied that logic with a few variations, but it is always printing something like this: 
Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => 37 [2] => 43 ).
Note that the values are right, but the keys are wrong. They should be: Array ( [Peter] => 35 [Ben] => 37 [Joe] => 43 )

Comment: Simple answer: don't create the string the way you are. Just create a string of your key-value pairs delimited by something. Then have a different delimiter to separate key and value.  Then explode the string into an array. Then print the array.

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290342/php-split-delimited-string-into-key-value-pairs-associative-array

Comment: Wow, It worked like a charm, now it's printing: 
Array ( [Peter] => 35 [Ben] => 37 [Joe] => 43 )
And just by using an simple implode and parse_str. I just had to work on the input string and Voilà! It's done! Thank you ecg8.